# Runnig geth in ec2 gives error, panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, ethereum, geth

> What Iam trying to achieve is to run an ethereum/client-go on an aws EC2
>   instance and being able to access it from remote client side, for playing around with Rinkeby test network

I am trying to run an `geth` docker image on ec2 instance on **aws**.
When I run the docker using the below command, I am getting the following error.

```
sudo docker run -it -p 8545:8545 -p 30303:30303 ethereum/client-go --rpc --rinkeby --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi 'db,eth,net,web3,personal' --rpcaddr XXX.XX.XXX.XXX --cache=1024
```

> Where **--rpcaddr XXX.XX.XXX.XXX** is my Elastic IP

```
INFO [04-17|10:24:08] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
INFO [04-17|10:24:08] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.8.4-unstable-92c6d130/linux-amd64/go1.10.1
INFO [04-17|10:24:08] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/root/.ethereum/rinkeby/geth/chaindata cache=768 handles=1024
INFO [04-17|10:24:08] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [04-17|10:24:08] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=355 size=65.27kB time=1.082517ms gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [04-17|10:24:08] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 4 Homestead: 1 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: true EIP150: 2 EIP155: 3 EIP158: 3 Byzantium: 1035301 Constantinople: <nil> Engine: clique}"
INFO [04-17|10:24:08] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=4
INFO [04-17|10:24:08] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=6341fd…67e177 td=1
INFO [04-17|10:24:08] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=6341fd…67e177 td=1
INFO [04-17|10:24:08] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=6341fd…67e177 td=1
INFO [04-17|10:24:08] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [04-17|10:24:08] Starting P2P networking 
INFO [04-17|10:24:10] UDP listener up                          self=enode://350e33a2680260f24bd1837e59610173769023f6cf609ab59b1aca63dc867cce5d7cb520343ed9a04b8a98d5a7d08f57f9e2ee258502312fafad42d005179aab@[::]:30303
INFO [04-17|10:24:10] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/root/.ethereum/rinkeby/geth.ipc
INFO [04-17|10:24:10] IPC endpoint closed                      endpoint=/root/.ethereum/rinkeby/geth.ipc
INFO [04-17|10:24:10] Blockchain manager stopped 
INFO [04-17|10:24:10] Stopping Ethereum protocol 
INFO [04-17|10:24:10] RLPx listener up                         self=enode://350e33a2680260f24bd1837e59610173769023f6cf609ab59b1aca63dc867cce5d7cb520343ed9a04b8a98d5a7d08f57f9e2ee258502312fafad42d005179aab@[::]:30303
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0xa6e76b]

goroutine 76 [running]:
github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/filters.(*EventSystem).eventLoop(0xc42c694d00)
    /go-ethereum/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/filters/filter_system.go:434 +0x2eb
created by github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/filters.NewEventSystem
    /go-ethereum/build/_workspace/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/eth/filters/filter_system.go:113 +0x104
```

> 1. Can anyone help, what is causing the above issue?

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0xa6e76b]
```

When I run the same docker with `--rpcaddr 127.0.0.1` it works fine, but cannot access from remote client,

```
sudo docker run -it -p 8545:8545 -p 30303:30303 ethereum/client-go --rpc --rinkeby --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi 'db,eth,net,web3,personal' --rpcaddr 127.0.0.1 --cache=1024
```

I have tried using,

- Public DNS (IPv4),
- IPv4 Public IP and
- Elastic IP

for the --rpcaddr values

Also I have given the security permission in aws TCP inbound and outbound ports.

Am i doing this right? Is this the right way to run web3 provider?

Comment: can you do? `--rpcaddr "0.0.0.0"` you need allow all (0.0.0.0) to connect from a remote client.

Comment: It removed the panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference, but when I am trying to connect to the provider from the same instance (using Web3) I am getting  
Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined  @SudharsanSivasankaran

Comment: `docker run -it -p 8545:8545 -p 30303:30303 ethereum/client-go --rpc --rinkeby --syncmode "fast" --rpc --rpcapi 'db,eth,net,web3,personal' --rpcaddr 0.0.0.0 --cache=1024`  can you check your command? its does work for me.

Comment: sudo docker ps 

doesn't show any container runnig.

Comment: sudo docker ps -a gives this details for the last command

31a421e78d30        ethereum/client-go   "geth --rpc --rinkeb…"   12 minutes ago      Exited (2) 10 minutes ago

Comment: can you check the logs for the exit error with `docker logs`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169165/discussion-between-siv-and-sudharsan-sivasankaran).

Answer (score 1):

You should be using volumes in my opinion because the client will try download the ethereum blockchain, but with your current setup there is nowhere to save the blockchain.

Have a look at this page: 
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Running-in-Docker
"To persist downloaded blockchain data between container starts, use Docker data volumes. Replace /path/on/host with the location you want to store the data in."

```
$ docker run -it -p 30303:30303 -v /path/on/host:/root/.ethereum ethereum/client-go
```

Try see if this helps. If you still have issues I'll be happy to try help or consider looking over the issues on github for geth. I saw someone got a similar error in 2017 and logged an issue see here: 
https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/15079

Comment: I have attached 28GB volume already, let me check again by killing all the process again.

Comment: Did you attach the volume to the container or to your ec2 instance?

Comment: Only to the instance.

Comment: Try with `$ docker ...-v /location-to-volume-you-mountedt:/root/.ethereum ` you can check where the volume was mounted on the ec2 instance if you run `df -h`